# Enabling Metrics with External Timings in Esper

Tags: java, esper

We're using Esper and Metrics Reporting are not working while external timings are enabled. When I disable the external timings, the metrics are back working again.

```
UpdateListener statsListener = this;

esper.getEpAdministrator().createEPL("select * from
com.espertech.esper.client.metric.EngineMetric",
QQQ_ENGINE_METRIC).addListener(statsListener);
esper.getEpAdministrator().createEPL("select * from
com.espertech.esper.client.metric.StatementMetric",
QQQ_STATEMENT_METRIC).addListener(statsListener);

//...

@Override
public void update(EventBean[] arg0, EventBean[] arg1) {
log.info("arg0 " + arg0 + ((arg0 != null) ? arg0.length : 0));
}
```

And I get no log output on the update method.

My esper.xml settings:

```
  <engine-settings>
    <defaults>
      <metrics-reporting enabled="true" jmx-engine-metrics="true"
engine-interval="1000" statement-interval="1000" threading="true"/>
    </defaults>
  </engine-settings>
```

We're using `CurrentTimeSpanEvent` as an external timing source.

```
esper.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeSpanEvent(lastEsperTime, 250));
```

We need external timings because we're running some automated tests on new EPL directives with old data and events, and the data rate on the tests are different than with the live data.

I also tried changing the CurrentTimeSpanEvent to a series of CurrentTimeEvents events:

```
if (originalEsperTime < lastEsperTime) {
    long tmptt = originalEsperTime;
    while (tmptt < lastEsperTime) {
        esper.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(tmptt));
        tmptt += 250;
    }
    esper.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(tmptt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to configure or set external-timer on? Or you forgot to set the time before creating statements? If you can provide a complete test class and not just code snippets this issue could probably be resolved by looking at the code.

Comment: I did as you asked, to create a sample program, and the metrics always works :( I have no idea what I've done wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Esper external timings should be initialized, initially, from the current system time, ie `System.currentTimeMillis()`. This is a basic use case where the metrics fail:

```
public class Main implements UpdateListener {
    public static class TestEvent {
        public TestEvent(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    private EPServiceProvider esper;
    private EPAdministrator epAdministrator;
    private EPRuntime epRuntime;

    private boolean externalTiming = true;
    private long currentTimeExternal;

    public void update(EventBean[] arg0, EventBean[] arg1) {
        if (arg0 != null && arg0.length > 0)
            System.out.println(new Date().toString() + " arg0: " + arg0[0]);
    }

    public void run() {
        Configuration esperConfig = new Configuration();
        esperConfig.configure(new java.io.File("esper.xml"));

        esper = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("AsantosEsperTest",
                esperConfig);
        epAdministrator = esper.getEPAdministrator();
        epRuntime = esper.getEPRuntime();

        // This breaks metrics. For the metrics to work, the initial timing
        // event on external timing should be system time at engine
        // initialization.
        currentTimeExternal = 0;

        initializeExternalTiming();
        initializeMetrics();
        initializeEventType();
        initializeStatements();

        while (true) {
            epRuntime.sendEvent(new TestEvent("QQQ"));

            if (externalTiming) {
                epRuntime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeSpanEvent(
                        currentTimeExternal));
                currentTimeExternal += 150 * 2;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(150);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeStatements() {
        epAdministrator.createEPL("select * from TestEvent").addListener(this);
    }

    private void initializeMetrics() {
        epAdministrator.createEPL(
                "select * from com.espertech.esper.client.metric.EngineMetric")
                .addListener(this);
        epAdministrator
                .createEPL(
                        "select * from com.espertech.esper.client.metric.StatementMetric")
                .addListener(this);
    }

    private void initializeExternalTiming() {
        if (externalTiming) {
            epRuntime.sendEvent(new TimerControlEvent(
                    TimerControlEvent.ClockType.CLOCK_EXTERNAL));
            epRuntime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(currentTimeExternal));
        }
    }

    private void initializeEventType() {
        epAdministrator.getConfiguration().addEventType(TestEvent.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();
    }
}
```

esper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<esper-configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.espertech.com/schema/esper"
  xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.espertech.com/schema/esper/esper-configuration-2.0.xsd">
  <engine-settings>
    <defaults>
      <metrics-reporting enabled="true" jmx-engine-metrics="true" engine-interval="1000" statement-interval="1000" threading="false"/>
    </defaults>
  </engine-settings>
</esper-configuration>
```